# Best way to remove word punctuation and re-add it later using Java?

Tags: java, string, if-statement, addition

```
[Running Java 1.7.0_51 on MacOSX]
```

Hello there,

I am currently writing a program, and have to write a method that will take a string parameter of a word, remove its punctuation, abbreviate the word itself, then once the word has been abbreviated, *re-add* the punctuation and return the word. 
*Note that the punctuation only includes:* `,` `;` `.` `!` `?`

The string parameter will be a *single word*, with punctuation **only** included at the *end*.

I already know how to do this with repeated if statements / else if, however I'd like to see an example of perhaps a better, more efficient way to do this if possible. I'm sure there's a better way, and that someone better experienced can give me an example. I'd be very grateful. I'm still learning but I'd like to explore efficient options!

**Example input:**

Thankyou!

**Example output:**

Ty!
*All I need guidance with is the actual removing and re-adding punctuation. Leave the abbreviating part to me. So to just simplify it, assume that the input and output is unchangeable.*

Comment: show the example input and output.

Comment: This question fits [Code Review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) better than here.

Comment: @zahz you also need to include what code you have already tried.

Comment: @AKS I would, but I can't. As this is an assignment of mine so I can't get too much help. All I need guidance with is the actual removing and re-adding punctuation. Leave the abbreviating part to me.

So to just simplify it, assume that the input and output is unchangeable. Hope this is understandable!

Comment: @AKS Although, the way with if statements I know will work, although it might not be the best way, is to check if the end of the input string includes a punctuation mark in an if statement, if so, remove them and store the punctuation mark in a variable. Then once it has been abbreviated, just append the punctuation mark to the string input, then output it. What I'm -trying- to avoid is a flood of if statements doing this though.

Comment: @zahz check my answer for using regex to match all the punctuation marks using one `if` condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering

> The punctuation mark is always at the end

You can get the punctuation mark from the `inputWord` as following:

```
String punctuation = inputWord.substring(inputWord.length() - 1);
```

and check it using regex if it is one of the punctuation mark you should have

```
if (punctuation.matches("[\\!\\,\\?\\;\\.]"))
    // your actions items here
```

this way you can avoid multiple `if` statements.

---

**Alternatively**

You can maintain a set of all the punctuation marks you need to check against:

```
Set<String> punctuationSet = new HashSet<String>(                                   
                        Arrays.asList(new String[]{"!", "?", ";", ",", "."}));
```

and later check if the `punctuation` in the `inputWord` is present in the `punctuationSet` using

```
if (punctuationSet.contains(punctuation))
    // your actions items here
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped a great deal, can't believe I forgot about regular expression there!

Comment: look at the alternative solution too :)

Comment: I used regular expression, worked like a charm. Thanks again for the alternative though!